# Reverse geocoding android pricing

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

If someone could help me. Is using geocoder free for android, currently i'm only using google maps. I see that it says that its only 2500 requests per day. Or is this only for web and something entirely different from mobile?

I am using the following code to get a zip code with a latitude and longitude.

```
 final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLocationClient.getLatitudeCoordinate(), mLocationClient.getLongitudeCordinate(),5);
        for (Address address: addresses){
            if(address.getLocality()!=null && address.getPostalCode()!=null){
                Log.v("Zip code", " " + address.getPostalCode());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

Just trying to make sure. I'm super confused on this and some clarification could help :) Thanks

Answer (score 17):

The Geocoder use is totally free.

The link you wrote is related to Google Maps and Google Places API, not the Geocoding API. This is the correct link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Anyway you are not using the Geocoding API with this code, you just using the Geocoder of Android.

This is the documentation to use the Geocoding API if you want:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

The Geocoding API works better than Geocoder normally but has usage limits and the implementation is bigger.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying this for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MarcGV Hi, is Geocoding service still free? I am confused because the link you gave (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) shows that it has a limit. Am I right?

Comment: Geocoder is free in Android but the Geocoding API has usage limits. Here the link for Geocoder: https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Answer (score 1):

Not any more. Google just decided to 10x their price for geocoding https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Comment: geocoder class is different from geocoding api, refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42536489/1529129